# App-clip and Instant App with Stripe payments using React Native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, android-instant-apps, apple-appclips

I am struggling to maintain the total size of my App Clip / Instant App under the prescribed 15mb.

I am using React Native and would like to keep doing so.
By create a new react native project and pulling out and in again Stripe, it seems that alone will take as much as 7mb of space, making it very hard to bundle observing the 15mb limit.

Do you happen to know a turnaround, or maybe is there something that I'm missing?
For reference this is the list of dependencies (with which I can manage to bundle into 15.1mb of total size):

````
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "@shopify/restyle": "^2.1.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.28.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.25.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.22.0",
    "ahooks": "^3.7.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18n-js": "^4.2.2",
    "immer": "^9.0.18",
    "jotai": "^1.13.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-app-clip": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "zustand": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@bitetechnology/bite-types": "^1.0.11",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^11.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.10",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.13",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
    "metro-minify-uglify": "^0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },```
````

Answer (score 2):

Not possible right now, but you can follow along on https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/947 which should be updated when this is available.